# Как сделать правильную сортировку строк в MySQL ?

Tags: сортировка, mysql

Создается база данных

```
    CREATE DATABASE Timetable
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET  utf8
    DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;

    USE Timetable;
```

В ней таблица

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
    ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    AnyText TINYTEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

В нее добавляются данные (utf8 withouut BOM)

INSERT INTO Test VALUES (NULL, 'Ам'), (NULL, 'Б'),(NULL, 'Б'),(NULL, 'Б'),(NULL, 'Г'), (NULL, 'Ж')

В результате  запроса

```
SELECT * FROM Test ORDER BY AnyText
```

получаем

```
ID  AnyText
24  Ж
20  Б
21  Б
22  Б
23  Г
19  Ам
```

Как получить адекватный ответ?

Comment: *Посмотрите настройки MySQL, формат полей и пр.*
*должны... в этом и проблема, что у вас данные записываются не так*

Попробую переставить MySQL и отпишусь. Это все происходит на Windows 7 x64 Ultimate English , редактор Notepad++.

Comment: Переустановил MySQL - все исправилось. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте направление сортировки - Desc[ по убыванию ] или Asc[ по возрастанию ] (по умолчанию Asc ) - хотя в вашем случае он, вроде-как, не сработал.

```
 order by field_name asc
```

Comment: Извините, возможно, я что-то не знаю, но TINYTEXT разве числовое? Почему тогда при смене TINYTEXT на CHAR (255), результат не меняется?

Comment: прошу прощения, плохо читал) просто есть тип - tinyint

Comment: Все равно не работает. Результат тот же.
Кстати, если "Ам" заменить на "А", то она становится в начале, но дальше все равно "Ж".

Comment: повторил всё что вы написали в вопросе - результат верный.

Comment: выполните и покажите результат

    SELECT CAST(  `AnyText` AS BINARY( 4 ) )  FROM  `Test`

Мой результат:

    CAST( `AnyText` AS BINARY( 4 ) )
    d090d0bc
    d0910000
    d0910000
    d0910000
    d0930000
    d0960000

Comment: CAST(  `AnyText` AS BINARY( 16 ) )
    ГђВђГђВј\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0
    ГђвЂ\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0
    ГђвЂ\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0
    ГђвЂ\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0
    ГђвЂњ\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0
    ГђвЂ“\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0

Comment: И что с этим нужно делать?
Кстати, а разве *все* русские/украинские буквы в utf8 не должны занимать по 2 байта?

Comment: Все должно работать нормально, как Вам показали запрос SELECT * FROM Test ORDER BY AnyText. Посмотрите настройки MySQL, формат полей и пр.

Comment: должны... в этом и проблема, что у вас данные записываются не так

Answer (score 0):

Используйте ASK или DESC для сортировки записей. И сразу возникает вопрос: строку Ам (id=19) Вы вводили на английском языке? Возможно по-этому она внизу.

Comment: Все буквы украинские. Несколько раз перепроверено.
ASC ничего не меняет.